# Visual Studio Code UI: Accidentally hid variables section in debug. How to get it back?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, show-hide

I feel a bit silly about this, but I seem to have accidentally hidden the variables section for debug mode in Visual Studio Code, and can't figure out how to get it back.

The debugger is starting ok (using node.js for debuggging a js file), and I can see Watch, Call Stack, and Breakpoints - but no Variables window. Have attached a screenshot to show the layout. 
[screeny of VS Code window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhiPc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the "*Go to File...*" menu and type in **view Variables** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will show the variables view again.